# React Native Webview error 1002 mailto link

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-webview

I'm running a website inside of a `react-native-webview` with some additional Javascript for iOS and Android in React Native (expo). This way we have an app, without having to create another codebase.

The problem is there are anchors with mailto in the href, these break the app on both platforms and return a `-1002` error on iOS and `-10` error on Android.

Is it possible to work something into the Webview to open the default mail app?